# accessing results outside of while and for loop php

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have start and finish times for my users

Times are in seconds in db and  converted in gmdate() in page
please keep in mind when you see the integers.

```
 user1 startTime = 9:00;  finishTime = 10:00;
 user2 startTime = 12:00;  finishTime = 1:00;

 <?php

 if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM times WHERE Id = $user->data()->id")){
    if($results->num_rows){

       $value = 1800;

      while($row = $results->fetch_array()){

         //This will return the startTime, finishTime, and any blocks of time in between them
         for($n_block = $row['timeStart']; $n_block <= $row['timeFinish']; $n_block+=$value){
            echo "$n_block<br>";
        }
     }
   }
 }
 ?>

 The desired results are:
 32400
 34200
 36000
 43200
 45000
 46800
```

But I need to put the results in an array that is accessed outside the loop

```
   // need to get above while and for loop results in this array outside the loops
   $excludes = array();
```

if I use $start = "";
please see http://pastie.org/9784700

if I take the for loop out of the while loop 
please see http://pastie.org/9784732

How do I achieve the desired results? Meaning how can I access the results of the combined loops outside of the loops?

```
var_dump($row);

array(18) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "5"
    ["appointmentCount"]=> string(1) "5"
    [1]=> string(2) "23"
    ["technicianId"]=> string(2) "23"
    [2]=> string(2) "22"
    ["customerId"]=> string(2) "22"
    [3]=> string(10) "1417129200"
    ["appointmentDay"]=> string(10) "1417129200"
    [4]=> string(5) "43200"
    ["appointmentStart"]=> string(5) "43200"
    [5]=> string(5) "46800"
    ["appointmentFinish"]=> string(5) "46800"
    [6]=> string(8) "FULL SET"
    ["serviceName"]=> string(8) "FULL SET"
    [7]=> string(2) "50"
    ["serviceCost"]=> string(2) "50"
    [8]=> string(8) "November"
    ["appointmentMonth"]=> string(8) "November" 
} 
array(18) {
    [0]=> string(1) "6"
    ["appointmentCount"]=> string(1) "6"
    [1]=> string(2) "23"
    ["technicianId"]=> string(2) "23"
    [2]=> string(2) "22"
    ["customerId"]=> string(2) "22"
    [3]=> string(10) "1417129200"
    ["appointmentDay"]=> string(10) "1417129200"
    [4]=> string(5) "32400"
    ["appointmentStart"]=> string(5) "32400"
    [5]=> string(5) "36000"
    ["appointmentFinish"]=> string(5) "36000"
    [6]=> string(8) "Nail Tip"
    ["serviceName"]=> string(8) "Nail Tip"
    [7]=> string(2) "30"
    ["serviceCost"]=> string(2) "30"
    [8]=> string(8) "November"
    ["appointmentMonth"]=> string(8) "November" 
}




<?php
if ($appointmentResults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE technicianId = $userid")){
    if($appointmentResults->num_rows){
        $start = "";
        $finish = "";
        $value = 1800;

        while($row = $appointmentResults->fetch_array()){
            $start .= $row['appointmentStart'] . '<br>';
            $finish .= $row['appointmentFinish'] . '<br>';

            for($n_block = $row['appointmentStart']; $n_block <= $row['appointmentFinish']; $n_block+=$value){
                echo "$n_block</br>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bcesars the loops work, I want to access the results outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$excludes = array();
if($appointmentResults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE technicianId = $userid")) {
    if($appointmentResults->num_rows) {
        $value = 1800;
        while($row = $appointmentResults->fetch_array()) {
            for($n_block = $row['appointmentStart']; $n_block <= $row['appointmentFinish']; $n_block+=$value){
                echo $n_block."</br>";
                $excludes[] = $n_block;
            }
        }
    }
}
sort($excludes);
print_r($excludes);
```

Comment: @helicode I tried that as well. When I var_dump($excludes); in the forloop I get duplicates of user2 and missing finishTime and middle times of user1.... outside for loop and while loop I get finishTimes of user1 and user2

Comment: Do a var_dump($row) inside your for loop. let's see your data. Also, have you shown your exact PHP code or could it differ from the "live" code?

Comment: no problem I have that ready as well. When I var_dump($row) it returns NULL

Comment: It shouldn't be Null -- that would mean you have no data. Sorry I meant the `while` loop. Put the `var_dump` just before the `for` statement.

Comment: @TomRobinson when var_dump($row) before for loop it returns all the data from the db

Comment: @tru that's what I would like to see. Could you paste the var_dump results in a comment or add it to the end of your question?

Comment: @TomRobinson I added to end of question

Comment: @tru: The second row has no timeStart and timeFinish, but appStart and appFinish! Which database is it that can produce different rows?

Comment: tru are you still using the code that you posted to Pastie, containing this line: `$start .= $row['timeStart'] . '<br>';` ???

@hellcode's question is a good one - how did the schema suddenly change between records?

Comment: that was me editing the results to the var dump, it had data i didnt want showed, I just didnt name them the same on the edit. I just reposted the raw dump without the edits. Where you see appointmentStart would be the same as timeStart

Comment: @TomRobinson the code below the newly posted var_dump is the code I am currently using

Comment: @hellcode print_r returns.....Array ( [0] => 43200 [1] => 45000 [2] => 46800 [3] => 32400 [4] => 34200 [5] => 36000 )

Comment: @tru: that are the desired times, but I have added a sort now. Hope this helps.

Comment: @hellcode thank you it is working but I do not understand, because I did that before as you can see in the pastbin, but I think I was focusing so much on being able to echo the data, not realizing that the data was stored in the array

Comment: thank you also @TomRobinson. ive been stuck on this for 2 weeks and I had the answer a few times and did not realize it. Looking left when I should have looked right.

Comment: @helicode I want to give you the credit as well but Tom had the same answer first. Im torn

Comment: @tru: no, first answer was mine (see mouseover on answered) ... but leave it as it is or just upvote both answers for the hard work ;-)

Comment: @hellcode you are correct. credit to you and may thanks to you both. I tried upvoting both but it would not let me. Hopefully someone else can upvote his as well

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your script, before the `if`, add:

```
    $excludes = array();
```

In your loop, right before `echo`, add:

```
    $excludes[] = $n_block;
```

When you drop out of the `if`, $excludes will be an array of the integers you want.

If the query fails to find any records, $excludes will be an empty array.

Comment: I tried that as well see what was said to helicode. If not I do not mind repeating. Thank you for the suggestion.......... helicode I tried that as well. When I var_dump($excludes); in the forloop I get duplicates of user2 and missing finishTime and middle times of user1.... outside for loop and while loop I get finishTimes of user1 and user2